# Tickets for the Italian F1 Grand Prix at Monza

Tags: italy, activities, events, formula-one, grands-prix

I'm looking for the buying the general admission tickets for the Italian F1 Grand Prix weekend. I have the following questions

1. Can I hope to get a good view with the general admission tickets?
2. Are the ticket prices expected to rise

Anybody experienced with buying F1 tickets?

Comment: Ticket prices for F1 events are fixed and don't 'rise', but tickets can get sold out. Most circuits will show a map of locations a ticket can get you in to along with what the view from there is. Another trick is to check multiple official F1 sites for the tickets; sometimes, due to exchange rates, you might get a better deal from one compared to another although some sites do block foreign credit cards.

Comment: See [What is a shopping question?](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/241/what-is-a-shopping-question/243#243) for why this was closed.